# Is this the correct cable wiring for a dewalt generator and a Lincoln pro-MIG 180?

Tags: generator, cables, welding

I have a Lincoln Pro-MIG 180 and a DeWalt DXGNR7000 generator. I have found a cable that is supposed to work. Can someone confirm this is correct wiring?

The generator does in fact have an L14-30R receptacle.

BTW the generator manual states that the neutral is bonded to the frame, as well as the ground.

Attached is an image from the website detailing the wiring diagram of the cable.

I was going to do the cable myself, but a purpose built item seems safer.
[image]

Comment: I use one of those, it works without problems

Comment: Just as a follow up, I wonder … would it still be okay if the generator’s neutral *wasn’t* bonded to the frame along with the ground?

Comment: @KerryThomas Neutral bonding is irrelevant in this case as the cable doesn’t connect neutral to the welder.

Comment: I also use one of those to plug my Yeswelder MP200 (with 6-50P) into an L14-30R outlet - works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks correct. I found information on [your welder (under Documentation)](https://www.lincolnelectric.com/en/products/k2481-1) which shows what must be a NEMA 6-50 outlet which matches your cable. (I do find it odd that they use a 50 amp-rated plug with a rated input current of 20 amps, but whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

Adapter cables with NEMA 6 sockets but NEMA 14 plugs are fine.

However, the assembly must either be UL Listed, or field assembled out of UL Listed parts. If this is a "mail order special", *and that really looks like an ordering screen from a mail order site*, then run screaming.

You may be better off assembling this yourself using appropriate plug, socket and *cordage*.  Your friendly electrical supply house can sell you all those things that are appropriate physical fits for each other.